# java - Problems with date

Tags: java, database, date, jpa

```
setTest (new Date ())
```

I put the Date value in the above format.
However, the value stored in the database is not `2018/03/15 18:00` but the invalid data `0001/03/15 18:00` is saved.
What's the problem?

Comment: It's impossible to answer a question with so little detail. Please share your code that inserts the value to the database.

Comment: check database format for this field

Comment: I recommend you avoid the `Date` class if you can, it is long outdated.  Instead use [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It is much nicer to work with. And I recommend you [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). The problem is somewhere in code that you haven’t shown to us, which you need to do if we’re to help.

Answer (score 1):

1. check whether you have imported proper date (java.util or java.sql)
2. if you have imported java.util.Date, check whether you have @Temporal annotation with proper configuration. 
   If this does not help, extend your question with more details.